# Read 2d array of string as parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm passing data from my database to my API.

```
string[,] vendors = new string[100, dr.FieldCount];
```

Assuming `vendors` has values.

My client is:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    string serialisedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vendors);
    var response = client.UploadString(getVendorURL, serialisedData);
    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);
}
```

And my API looks like:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetVendorExport([FromBody]string[,] vendors)
{      
    return Ok("This is a string");
}
```

vendors is null. What seems to be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Note that that's a 2d array, not a jagged array (an array of arrays).

Comment: what does the json look like?